# Rename file names containing spaces .ksh

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I'm trying to rename my files containing spaces. IFS=$'\n' actually worked as FOR loop can now handle those file names with spaces. Unfortunately, all .csv files in DIR are inserted in variable FL which results to error. Is there a way for variable FL to handle one file at a time while it also handles spacing in the file name?

script:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for FL in `ls -1 ${DIR}/*.csv`
do
FL_DP=`echo ${FL}`
FL_RN=`echo ${FL_DP} | tr -d '[:blank:]'`
mv ${FL_DP} ${FL_RN}
done
```

Result:

```
+ IFS=$\n
+ ls -1 test _1.csv test _2.csv
++ echo test _1.csv
test _2.csv
FL_DP=test _1.csv
test _2.csv
++ echo test _1.csv
test _2.csv
FL_RN=test_1.csv
test_2.csv
+ mv test _1.csv
test _2.csv test_1.csv
test_2.csv
mv: cannot access test _1.csv
test _2.csv
```

Expected Result:

```
+ ls -1 test _1.csv test _2.csv
++ echo test _1.csv
FL_DP=test _1.csv
++ echo test _1.csv
FL_RN=test_1.csv
mv test _1.csv test_1.csv
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at 
[**How does deleting work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)

Answer (score 1):

You may just need to quote the variable with spaces. But @Cyrus has a good point about parsing ls output. While tempting, it should be considered human readable data.

Here's how you might do this without ls:

```
for f in "$dir"/*.csv; do mv -i "$dir/$f" "$dir/${f// /}"; done
```

Comment: i tried the query you provided but i get an error message

Comment: It worked for me using bash 4.4. What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: $dir/${f// /} bad substitution

Comment: I thought the string substitution was compatible with ksh. Checking now

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your error. It worked fine for me in ksh version (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01

Comment: What shell and version are you using?

Comment: You could try adding curly brackets around the dir variable, but they shouldn't be needed in that context

Comment: If ksh --version prints an error, then you've probably got an old version of ksh

Comment: @jjang: Add your shebang to your question and how do you start your script?

Comment: @RobC I don't see that danger. The space substitution is only being applied to the filename variable. I'm also including the -i interactive flag so that there will be a prompt if anything is about to be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Change from `backticks` to `"quotes"` in FL_DP

Don't parse ls, just use `for file in dirname..`

```
IFS=$'\n'
for FL in {DIR}/*.csv
do
  FL_DP="${FL}"
  FL_RN=`echo ${FL_DP} | tr -d '[:blank:]'`
  mv ${FL_DP} ${FL_RN}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using find, while and read:

```
find . -type f | while
  read filename
do
  echo "$filename"
done
```

Here's how you can apply the above construct to your particular question:

```
find $DIR -name '*.csv' -type f | while
  read filename
do
  mv "$filename" ${filename/ /}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it find `find` and `awk` commands

```
find . -name "*.csv" -printf "mv \"%f\" |\"%f\" \n" | awk  -F"|" ' { gsub(" ","",$2); print } '
```

Sample testing

```
$ ls -1 *csv
scores.csv
'test _1.csv'
'test _2.csv'
$ find . -name "*.csv" -printf "mv \"%f\" |\"%f\" \n" | awk  -F"|" ' { gsub(" ","",$2); print } '
mv "scores.csv"  "scores.csv"
mv "test _1.csv"  "test_1.csv"
mv "test _2.csv"  "test_2.csv"
$
```

Here printf prints file name using %f identifier, just add a pipe and print the file name 2 times.

I used pipe here, because that will not appear in filename. Now pass the results to awk command with "|" as delimiter and replace spaces using gsub() function.

The final results could be passed again to ksh to execute them

Hope this helps